# Why and When should I use Functional Interfaces

Tags: java, lambda, method-reference, functional-interface

Say I am writing a `Consumer` which prints something on the console. Then why shouldn't I directly use the `System.out.println()` method instead of creating a `Consumer`?

Similarly, say I want to return a *random number*, then we can use `Random` object directly in a normal method to return a number rather than using a `Supplier` to do so.

So why should one use `Consumer` and `Supplier`? What benefits does it bring?

Answer (score 1):

Functional interfaces should of course only be used where it is reasonable, and not *everywhere*. It is closely related to abstraction and generalization. Good examples for this can be seen in the Java SE API, for example for the [`java.util.stream.Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html) interface. The `Stream.map(Function)` method cannot know how a user would want to transform elements. Therefore it takes a `Function` and lets the user implement it in whatever way they like.

Unless you are writing a (general-purpose) library, there is normally no need to directly use functional interfaces yourself for method parameters. Normal inheritance and usage of interfaces should suffice for most use cases.
If you find a situation in your code where a functional interface would help, and the functional interface is needed for a specific usecase, it might be benefitial to define your own one instead of using standard one from the  `java.util.function` package. This allows you to restrict input and output types and write custom documentation, compared to using something as nonexpressive as `Function.apply`.

Answer (score 0):

> a Consumer which prints something on console. Then why shouldn't I directly use the System.out.println() method instead of creating a Consumer?

There's nothing wrong with printing something by simply using `System.out.println()`. When it's a *single* almost *isolated* action like in your example, there's no room and no need to entail anything else. Conversely, if you would write in the main something like that it would look contrived:

```
Consumer<String> myConsumer = System.out::println;
myConsumer.accept("Hello Functions!");
```

There's no reason to replace a single statement that is clear to every beginner by the consumer here. Don't add the functionality that is not required, as the [**YAGNI principle**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) suggests.

Let's look at the cases when the functional interfaces can be beneficial.

#### An Interface means a Contract

First of all, **interfaces** are meant to provide **contract**.

Thy are particularly useful when you want to ***generalize*** something, and *functional interfaces* are not an exception.

Let's consider the following *example*.

You have a couple of *methods*. One logs a message, another send some kind of request, the third sends an email, etc. And all these methods expects the same object, let's say of type `Event` as *parameter*. That means, each of these *methods* could be used as an *implementation* of `Supplier<Event>`.

Also, we have a group of *methods* that are calling these methods. And maybe they are not differ a lot. Let's assume each of the *methods* in this group is responsible for performing some kind of specific checks, then it processes the data and invokes one of the methods mentioned above.

With that, we can potentially refactor this second group of methods by contracting it to a *single generalized method* with such a signature:

```
public void processEvent(List<Event> events, 
                             UnaryOperator<Event> operator, 
                             Predicate<Event> predicate, 
                             Consumer<Event> consumer)
```

#### Leave the Streams alone

There is a *delusion* that functions could be used only with streams. No, that totally fine if, let's say, your method that doesn't utilize stream anyhow expects a predicate (or other functional interface build in the JDK). That allow you to make the behavior of your classes more flexible. You can define a predicate inline when calling a method

```
doSomething(person, person -> person.getAge() > 30);
doSomething(person, person -> person.getAge() <= 25);
doSomethingElse(token, MyToken::isValid);
```

And inside the method, use it like that:

```
if (myPred.test(token)) { // do }
```

Another option is you to maintain a collection of functions in order to reuse the behavior they are representing and provide convenient access to them. For instance:

```
Map<MyEnum, Function<EventDTO, Event>> funcByEnum = ...;
Event myEvent = funcByEnum.get(enum).apply(dto);
```

#### Implementing Functional interfaces

Also, your classes can **implement** *functional interfaces*.

As an example from the JDK - a group of *summary statistics* classes like [`IntSummaryStatistics`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/IntConsumer.html) that are implementing different flavors of ***consumer***. And you can modify a summary statistics object by using method `accept()`:

```
stat.accept(1000);
```

That allows to benefit from the ***self-explanatory names*** of methods defined by build in functional interfaces.

Names `test`, `accept` will be easily understood by anyone needs to read code (assuming they meat with a purpose of your methods).